# jQuery issue with live click and input named "name"

Tags: jquery

jQuery live click isn't working form me if form contains input named "name". Changing name to something else helps. Can anyone tell me why that happens?

If there is a field name "named" live click is not working when I click input named "value". If I change name from "name" to "name2" clicking on field named "value" works.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
$('form[name="prepare"] input[name="value"]').live('click', function(){
    alert('Clicked!');
    return false;
});
</script>

<form name="prepare" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="text" name="value" />
</form>
```

Comment: Seems like it’s got nothing to do with the `input[name="name"]`, but with the `form[name="prepare"]`.

Answer (score 1):

if you address your `<form>` by `id` instead of by `name` the bug disappears:

```
<form name="prepare" method="post" id="myform">

$('form#myform input[id="value"]').click(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `name="prepare"` attribute/value pair of the `FORM` element to `id="prepare"` and it should work, [like so](http://jsbin.com/itoco):

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
   $('form#prepare input[name=value]').live('click', function() {
    alert('Clicked!');
    return false;
   });
  </script>
 <form id="prepare" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="value">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

[html specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3):

> `<form>`, name=
>
> Note. This attribute has been included for backwards compatibility. Applications should use the id attribute to identify elements.

Since this attribute is deprecated, jquery may process it incorrectly.