# error in login- php/ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

i have a simple form to validate if an user exists in the db, and permit the login to another page (yes i remove the password validation to simplify the code, and i test without pass and the script always show Your login is not valid).

Database: emprego, table: users, fields: id, username, email, pass

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#login_form").submit(function () {
        $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Validating....').fadeIn(1000);
        $.post("ajax_login.php", {
            name: $('#name').val(),
        }, function (data) {
            if (data == 'yes') {
                $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function () {
                    $(this).html('Logging in.....').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900, 1, function () {
                        document.location = 'secure.php';
                    });
                });
            } else {
                $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200, 0.1, function () {
                    $(this).html('Your login is not valid').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900, 1);
                });
            }
        });
        return false; 
    });
}); 
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="" id="login_form">
                    User Name : <input name="name" type="text" id="name">
                <div class="buttondiv">
                    <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" style="margin-left:-10px; height:23px">
                    <span id="msgbox" style="display:none"></span>
                </div>
        </form>
```

file: ajax_login.php

```
<?php 

include("includes/f_banco.php");
conecta ();


$check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username ='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."'")or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($check);

if ($row['username'] == $_POST['name']) {
    echo "yes";
    $_SESSION['name']=$row['username'];
}else{echo "no";}

?>
```

EDIT: updated code

what is the possible cause?

Comment: Why don't you use `true` or `false`? `yes` and `no` just means you need to write more code.

Comment: ok, but the problem is not that, correct? thanks

Comment: What is the problem and what is the question?

Comment: i have an user in the BD but the login don't work with this username. it's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see lots of problems

```
<?php  
//removed the # from the post
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
//whys this here?
$row=mysql_fetch_array($check);
//name cant be used (common mistake)
$check = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE name ='".$name."'")or die(mysql_error());
$check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);
if ($check2 == 1) {
    echo "yes";
    $_SESSION['name']=$name;
}

else
echo "no";
?>
```

try something like this

```
<?php  
session_start();
include("includes/f_banco.php");
conecta ();

if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){echo "yes";}else{
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username ='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."' LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($check);

    if ($row['username'] == $_POST['name']) {
        echo "yes";
        $_SESSION['name']=$row['username'];
    }else{echo "no";}
}


?>
```

Comment: i just copy your code, change the name of the field in the bd to username but i can do the "login". It can be a problem in the JS?

Comment: test your php with a normal form, are you starting the session with session_start() in both ajax_login.php and the form page?

Comment: at the moment my code is equal to the post that is updated, thanks Lawrence

Comment: put session_start(); under <?php

Comment: login not valid, again, and again. I can't understand this problem.

Comment: but if i change to data=="no"; the result is login not valid, then the php file no returns yes or no...

Comment: ive updated the ajax_login.php example, directly goto it and see what it says. sometimes the most simplistic things get confusing lol

Comment: man solved, with this $username=htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'],ENT_QUOTES); unbelievable, thanks for your help, i really appreciate

Comment: dude im totally confused, vote me up if i was helpful lol im noobing at 186 :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the use of the field name "name"? See [jQuery issue with live click and input named "name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995166/jquery-issue-with-live-click-and-input-named-name)

Comment: no, i changed to name1 and i can't do the login, unbelievable this issue. Thanks